# Configure Redis Cluster in Ubuntu Server 14.04

Tags: redis, cluster-computing, redis-cli, redis-server

I've installed `redis-server` using `apt-get install redis-server` and everything went fine.

Right now I'm trying to configure it in a Cluster mode. The problem is that in the tutorial supplied here http://redis.io/topics/cluster-tutorial they use a script called `redis-trib.rb` which I can't find it in my system.

Can you please tell me how can I configure my Redis to run in Cluster mode without that script ?

I would like to have a setup with two masters, each on a different machine.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need Redis 3.0.0 beta to run Cluster. You'll not find it in a Linux distribution, since they all have copy of the stable server (fortunately!). Redis 3.0.0 will go out as a stable release the next week. You can find the source code of the stable release here: http://redis.io/download.

Comment: It so happens that I needed Redis 3.0.0 on Ubuntu 14.10 so I just put packages (based on Chris's debian package) [here](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/ubuntu/14.10/amd64/).  This uses the Redis 3.0.0RC sources from the experimental branch of the [repo used by Chris](https://github.com/lamby/pkg-redis/tree/experimental) for his Debian packaging.

Comment: Thanks @Dirk. I'll use your repo as suggested. Have a great day !

Comment: They seem to work fine for me, but note it is not a repo -- just download the two `.deb` files and install them.  And should I make this an answer then?  ;-)

Answer (score 3):

Had same problem with `reredis-trib.rb`
This tutorial explains how to create Redis Cluster using only Redis commands: [Configuring and Running Redis Cluster on Linux](http://codeflex.co/configuring-redis-cluster-on-linux/)

Answer (score 1):

There is now a tutorial for Ubuntu at https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-a-redis-cluster-on-ubuntu-14-04 which includes installation of a PPA to supply 3.0.x. This tutorial is only for two nodes and does not reference `redis-trib.rb` ...